# Last gift in Brunch Canyon

Tags: chicory

The gift NPC says there is one more gift/outfit in Bunch Canyon's seven screens, but I've been through all the flowers and don't see any hidden gifts. I have the one behind the corrupt tree (up the waterfall) but I imagine there's just a really hidden one--where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hidden on the first screen when entering the canyon from the right (from Brekkie).

> To reach it, you'll need to go forward and then backtrack across two screens to reach the cliff on the left, hopping across the waterway chasm leading into the canyon.

> [image: along the cliff to the left] [image: cross the chasm]